# VB.NET GroupBy element selector parameter type cannot be inferred

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

I can do this without a problem in c#:

```
public class Whatever
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

var whatevers = new[] {
    new Whatever { State = "SomeState", City = "Eastville" },
    new Whatever { State = "SomeState", City = "Southville" }
};

var group = whatevers.GroupBy(
    x => x.State, x => x.City, 
    (k, v) => new { State = k, Cities = v.ToArray() }
).ToArray();
```

But VB.NET seems to have inference issues:

```
Option Infer On

Public Class Whatever
    Property State As String
    Property City As String
End Class

Dim whatevers = New Whatever() {
    New Whatever With {.State = "SomeState", .City = "Eastville"},
    New Whatever With {.State = "SomeState", .City = "Southville"}
}

Dim group = whatevers.GroupBy(
    Function(x) x.State,
    Function(x) x, 'this is the problem; see below
    Function(k, v) New With {.State = k, .Cities = v.ToArray()}
).ToArray()
```

For my element selector, I want to return `Function(x) x.City`.  If I don't specify `.City`, `x` infers properly as `Whatever`.  However, the moment I type `.City`, `x` can no longer be inferred.

I've spent over an hour on this, so time to come to SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little fix can do the magic.

```
Public Class Whatever
  Property State As String
  Property City As String
End Class

Dim whatevers = New Whatever() {
    New Whatever With {.State = "SomeState", .City = "Eastville"},
    New Whatever With {.State = "SomeState", .City = "Southville"}
}

Dim group = whatevers.GroupBy(
    Function(x As Whatever) x.State,
    Function(x As Whatever) x.City, 'this is not the problem;
    Function(k, v) New With {.State = k, .Cities = v.ToArray()}
).ToArray()
```

Comment: That worked!  No idea why you'd have to do that in VB.NET, but not C#.

Comment: There are also lot of things that are possible in VB.NET, but not in C# :)

Comment: I actually think it's a bug in the IDE rather than a feature.  It can infer the type at first, but is then unable to as soon as I use the type initializer.

Comment: That is very possible. Try to use "Report a problem..." command in VS, but do not expect any response other than "Triaged".